# Numbers Keyboard in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, textfield

Does any one know how to show the numbers keyboard in the iphone rather than the default one? And is there a way to filter the textfield for numbers only? I need to do that from the code not from interface builder

Thanks

Comment: From 2013 ... simply set it as you wish in InterfaceBuilder

Answer (score 31, accepted):

alternatively, set the textfield's keyboardType property in code:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
```

Available options are:

> UIKeyboardType The type of keyboard to
>   display for a given text-based view.
>
> typedef enum {
>   UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
>   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
>   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
>   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
>   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
>   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
>   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
>   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
>   UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet =
>   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable }
>   UIKeyboardType;

A word of caution though, The NumberPad doesn't have a decimal point for entry. If you need that you'll have to use something else.

Answer (score 9):

There's a keyboard with a decimal included now, you can use the following code.

`textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `keyboardType` property of the entry field to be numeric, either in Interface Builder or via code.

Something like this should work:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

For all the possible keyboard types see [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType)

Comment: @Jeff Kelley the code was added after thary's comment was made.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Kristopher Johnson's answer, `UITextField` supports the `UITextInputTraits` protocol, which has a `UIKeyboardType` `@property` called `keyboardType`. You just set that to be whatever you want (in your case, `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`). One place to put this in your code is in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller.

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift2**

keyboardType is waiting a **UIKeyboardType**

> enum UIKeyboardType : Int {
>   case Default
>   case ASCIICapable
>   case NumbersAndPunctuation
>   case URL
>   case NumberPad
>   case PhonePad
>   case NamePhonePad
>   case EmailAddress
>   case DecimalPad
>   case Twitter
>   case WebSearch
>   static var Alphabet: UIKeyboardType { get }
>   }

So it should be something like this :

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
```

[Apple Documentation - UIKeyboardType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType)